# ROC and multiROC analysis: how to calculate optimal cutpoint?

Tags: r, roc, sensitivity-analysis, sensitivity-specificity

I'm trying to understand how to compute the optimal cut-point for a ROC curve (the value at which the sensitivity and specificity are maximized).
I'm using the dataset `aSAH` from the package `pROC`.

The `outcome` variable could be explained by two independent variables: `s100b` and `ndka`.
Using the syntax of the `Epi` package, I've created two models:

```
library(pROC)
library(Epi)
ROC(form=outcome~s100b, data=aSAH)
ROC(form=outcome~ndka, data=aSAH)
```

The output is illustrated in the following two graphs:

[image]
[image]

In the first graph (`s100b`), the function says that the optimal cut-point is localized at the value corresponding to `lr.eta=0.304`. In the second graph (`ndka`) the optimal cut-point is localized at the corresponding value to `lr.eta=0.335` (what is the meaning of `lr.eta`). My first question is:

- what is the corresponding `s100b` and `ndka` values for the `lr.eta` values indicated (what is the optimal cut-point in terms of `s100b` and `ndka`)?

**SECOND QUESTION:**

Now suppose I create a model taking into account both variable:

```
ROC(form=outcome~ndka+s100b, data=aSAH)
```

The graph obtained is:

[image]

I want to know what are the values of `ndka` AND `s100b` at which sensibility and specificity are maximized by the function. In other terms: what are the values of `ndka` and `s100b` at which we have Se=68.3% and Sp=76.4% (values derived from the graph)?

I suppose this second question is related to multiROC analysis, but the documentation of the `Epi` package does not explain how to calculate the optimal cutpoint for *both* variables used in the model.

My question appears very similar to this question from [reasearchGate](http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_determine_the_cut-off_score_for_optimal_combination_of_multiple_indicators_in_ROC_curve_analysis), which says in short:

> The determination of cut-off score that represents a better trade-off
>   between sensitivity and specificity of a measure is straightforward.
>   However, for multivariate ROC curve analysis, I have noted that most
>   of the researchers have focused on algorithms to determine the overall
>   accuracy of a linear combination of several indicators (variables) in
>   terms of AUC. [...]
>
> However, these methods do not mention how to decide a combination of
>   cut-off scores associated with the multiple indicators that gives the
>   best diagnostic accuracy.

A possible solution is that proposed by Shultz in his [paper](http://www.clinchem.org/content/41/8/1248.full.pdf), but from this article I'm not able to understand how to compute optimal cutpoint for a multivariate ROC curve.

Maybe the solution from the `Epi` package is not ideal, so any other helpful links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To elaborate on Frank Harrell's answer, what the `Epi` package did was to fit a logistic regression, and make a ROC curve with outcome predictions of the following form:

$$
outcome = \frac {1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 s100b + \beta_2 ndka)}}
$$

In your case, the fitted values are $\beta_0$ (intercept) = -2.379, $\beta_1$ (s100b) = 5.334 and $\beta_2$ (ndka) = 0.031. As you want your predicted outcome to be 0.312 (the "optimal" cutoff), you can then substitute this as (hope I didn't introduce errors here):

$$
0.312 = \frac {1}{1+e^{-(-2.379 + 5.334 s100b + 0.031 ndka)}}
$$
$$
1.588214 = 5.334  s100b + 0.031 ndka
$$
or:
$$
s100b = \frac{1.588214 - 0.031 ndka}{5.334}
$$

Any pair of (s100b, ndka) values that satisfy this equality is "optimal". Bad luck for you, there are an infinity of these pairs. For instance, (0.29, 1), (0, 51.2), etc. Even worse, most of them don't make any sense. What does the pair (-580, 10000) mean? Nothing!

In other words, you can't establish cut-offs on the inputs - you have to do it on the outputs, and that's the whole point of the model.

Comment: The logical follow-up question is: if we were faced with the task of considering a cutoff point based on the `lr.eta` in a model with only one explanatory variable, say `s100b`, would it be OK to select a cut-off point based on the `lr.eta`, excepting medical considerations regarding cost assigned to missed diagnoses, unnecessary procedures, etc?

Answer (score 8):

It is not appropriate to seek cutoffs on input variables, but instead only on the output (e.g., predicted risk from a multivariable model).  That is because the cutoff for x1 would depend on the continuous value of x2.  And seeking a cutpoint on $\hat{Y}$, to obtain optimum decisions, requires a utility/loss/cost function and this has nothing to do with ROC curves.

Comment: I understand the problem you explained. I'm wondering, by the way, if there is a method to calculate cut-off points for two (or more) tests in parallel, in order to increase the Sens and Spec of identifying a specific status (disease/outcome/etc.). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the "optimum" cutpoint for x1 would depend on the continuous value of x2, and the "optimum" cutpoint for x2 would depend on the continuous value of x1, there is no way to do this and preserve enough information to make it not a disaster.

Comment: So there is no way to find cut-off points for two or more tests, in order to maximize Sensibility and Specificity? Of course a method which is not a multiROC analysis. Thanks again.

Comment: It is simply not appropriate to seek cutoffs on inputs.  Optimum decisions are made using no cutoffs at all, or, if needed before decision time, by making cutoffs on the predicted probabilities.  Utilities (loss/cost) are needed to solve for the optimum cutoff on predicted risk.

Comment: ROC curves have nothing whatsoever to do with meeting that goal.  To do that you'd need to relate SCr to outcome, or just compute the probability of getting a more extreme SCr than that in a normal population.

Comment: I erased my comment by mistake...Thank you for your answer. Approximately I was asking if `lr.eta` could be used to, for instance, to establish a cutoff threshold between normal and elevated values of creatinine in a given laboratory. Not asking again, I just didn't want for anybody reading your post not to follow.

Comment: That would be completely inconsistent with optimal decision making.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess `lr.eta` is the linear predictor—the logit—from the fitted model, as $\eta$ is a commonly used symbol for it; or, if not, the probability from the fitted model. (Turns out it's the latter: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38532555/1864816.) You can check the code in `ROC`. In any case you'll be able to calculate it from the model coefficients for any number of predictors. (Note that it won't be a cut-off for each predictor separately, but a function of all predictors.)

Your first sentence should say (as evidenced by the graphs) that you're looking for where the *sum* of sensitivity & specificity is maximized. But why is this "optimal"? Does a false positive result have the same import as a false negative result? See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14153/based-only-on-these-sensitivity-and-specificity-values-what-is-the-best-decisio/14178#14178).

Comment: It was correct, I can calculate cut-off point from the fitted model (for one independent variable), or alternatively using the `coords` function from the `pROC` package, as I found later. The optimal cut-off point was, in my case, the best combination of Sens and Spec; I read the linked answer, but I don't care (at least for now) about false positive and false negative results, because (if I understood well) I'm analyzing a group of collected data for research.

Comment: What *do* you care about then? What are you doing with the cut-off that doesn't require any consideration of consequences? And then what is it 'optimal' or 'best' *for*?

Comment: Tommaso defined "optimal" as "the value at which the sensitivity and specificity are maximized" (quoting the first sentence of the question), implicitly meaning max(sensitivity + specificity). Whether it makes sense or not (and when I read he doesn't care, I am inclined to think it does not) is an other question.

Comment: This approach is at odds with decision making.

Comment: I think that if I am reading your post correctly, `lr.eta` is *exactly* the second option that you mention: the probability from the fitted model: $E[Yi|Xi]=11+e−(β0+β1×s100b)$. [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38532555/4089351) if you have a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the threshold at which the true positive rate (tpr) intersects the true negative rate (tnr) this will be point at which the sum of the false positives and false negatives is a minimum.

Comment: A one-sentence answer is typically regarded as a little short for our format. Can you expand your answer to include a brief explanation of how you know that's where the minimum must be?

Comment: Such a strategy flies in the face of optimum decision making.