# How can I get cut-off point in multivariated ROC analysis

Tags: roc, auc

If I have 1 independent variable (continues) and 1 dependent variable (binary), I can conduct logistic regression and ROC analysis, and I can get a cut-off point of independent variable using ROC analysis.

But, If I have 2 independent variable, how can I get two cut-off point in multivariate ROC analysis.

In STATA, I can get just maximal AUC score but I can't get the cut-off points each independent variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because with logistic regression you have an infinity of cut-off points that will correspond to each cut-off of the ROC curve. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67560/roc-and-multiroc-analysis-how-to-calculate-optimal-cutpoint/85413#85413) for more details.